# How to Save OpenCV (JavaCV) Trained Faces pictures to database?

Tags: java, mysql, opencv, javacv

Recently I complete a project about face recognition using JavaCV. it save faces to computer directory but i want to save those faces to RDBMs like SQLite, MySQL would be welcome.

Code for save image to computer directory

```
private String createPictureFilePathName(File dir) {
    File file = new File(dir.getPath() + "/image-0.png");
    int counter = 1;
    while (file.exists()) {
        file = new File(dir.getPath() + "/image-" + counter + ".png");
        counter++;
    }
    return file.getPath();
}

private static JFileChooser initPictureDirChooser() {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")).getAbsoluteFile());
        return chooser;
    }
```

Any leads to make this possible to save images to database?

Comment: Get the input stream of the file and save it into db as a blob using preparedstatement.

Comment: @AndyJones I've found some tutorials: [Example to store image in Oracle database](http://www.javatpoint.com/storing-image-in-oracle-database) and [How To Insert Image In MySQL Database In Java](http://1bestcsharp.blogspot.com/2015/04/java-how-to-insert-image-in-mysql-Database-Using-Java.html). Soon i'll implement when I'll get free from my busy schedule.

Comment: @webcoder is it possible to do it without using InputStream?

Basically i want to capture face and save it directly into database.

Answer (score 0):

Get the input stream of the file and save it into db as a blob using preparedstatement.

Example Code :

```
public boolean saveFile(File file) throws Exception{
    boolean completed = false;
    ConnectionManager conn = new ConnectionManager();
    try {
        PreparedStatement statement = conn.getConnection().prepareStatement("QUERY_TO_INSERT_FILE");
        statement.setBlob(1, file.getInputStream());           
        statement.execute();
        conn.commit();
        completed = true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        conn.rollbackQuietly();
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        conn.close();
    }                           
    return completed;       
}
```